# Discord.js Get user from reactions **Updated**

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

**Update**

I have updated the code that is currently working for me, It will now create the channel and then check to see if the channel is create. It will only allow 1 user to create a channel you will not be able to create a T5 channel and a T4 channel as the same user.

Thank you and I hope you all have a great Christmas.

```js
Client.on("message", async (message) => {
  if (message.author.Client || message.channel.type === "dm") return;

  let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
  let cmd = messageArray[0];
  let args = message.content.substring(message.content.indexOf(" ") + 1);

  if (cmd === `${prefix}battle`) {
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("⚔️ 1657 Battles! ⚔️")
      .setDescription("React to this message to join the battle.")
      .addFields(
        { name: "", value: "T5" },
        { name: "", value: "T4" },
        { name: "", value: "T3" },
        { name: "", value: "T2" },
        { name: "", value: "T1" }
      )
      .setColor("#0099ff")
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter("Please pick the troop type you want to battle with!");

    let msgEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
    msgEmbed.react(""); // T5
    msgEmbed.react(""); // T4
    msgEmbed.react(""); // T3
    msgEmbed.react(""); // T2
    msgEmbed.react(""); // T1
  }
});

Client.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user, message) => {
  //Add an event listener
  if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
  if (user.id === Client.user.id) return; //If the reaction was from the bot, return
  if (!reaction.message.guild) return; //If the reaction was not in a guild
  const guild = Client.guilds.cache.get("644295524404428832");
  if (
    guild.channels.cache.find((channel) => channel.name === "t5-battle-channel")
  )
    return;

  if (reaction.emoji.name === "") {
    let guild = reaction.message.guild;
    guild.channels.create("T5 Battle Channel", {
      //Creating the channel
      type: "text", //Make sure the channel type is text
      permissionOverwrites: [
        //Set overwrites
        {
          id: guild.id,
          deny: "VIEW_CHANNEL",
        },
        {
          id: "788400016736780338",
          allow: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"],
        },
      ],
    });
  }
  if (
    guild.channels.cache.find((channel) => channel.name === "t4-battle-channel")
  )
    return;

  if (reaction.emoji.name === "") {
    let guild = reaction.message.guild;
    guild.channels.create("T4 Battle Channel", {
      //Creating the channel
      type: "text", //Make sure the channel type is text
      permissionOverwrites: [
        //Set overwrites
        {
          id: guild.id,
          deny: "VIEW_CHANNEL",
        },
        {
          id: "788400619114463275",
          allow: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"],
        },
      ],
    });
  }
  if (
    guild.channels.cache.find((channel) => channel.name === "t3-battle-channel")
  )
    return;

  if (reaction.emoji.name === "") {
    let guild = reaction.message.guild;
    guild.channels.create("T3 Battle Channel", {
      //Creating the channel
      type: "text", //Make sure the channel type is text
      permissionOverwrites: [
        //Set overwrites
        {
          id: guild.id,
          deny: "VIEW_CHANNEL",
        },
        {
          id: "788400701130670110",
          allow: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"],
        },
      ],
    });
  }
  if (
    guild.channels.cache.find((channel) => channel.name === "t2-battle-channel")
  )
    return;

  if (reaction.emoji.name === "") {
    let guild = reaction.message.guild;
    guild.channels.create("T2 Battle Channel", {
      //Creating the channel
      type: "text", //Make sure the channel type is text
      permissionOverwrites: [
        //Set overwrites
        {
          id: guild.id,
          deny: "VIEW_CHANNEL",
        },
        {
          id: "788400738727624704",
          allow: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"],
        },
      ],
    });
  }
  if (
    guild.channels.cache.find((channel) => channel.name === "t1-battle-channel")
  )
    return;

  if (reaction.emoji.name === "") {
    let guild = reaction.message.guild;
    guild.channels.create("T1 Battle Channel", {
      //Creating the channel
      type: "text", //Make sure the channel type is text
      permissionOverwrites: [
        //Set overwrites
        {
          id: guild.id,
          deny: "VIEW_CHANNEL",
        },
        {
          id: "788400784420372490",
          allow: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"],
        },
      ],
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get all of the reactions on a message, you can use the [`reactions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=reactions) property on a [`message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message), if you already have the message object. This will return a [ReactionManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionManager) which you can use.

Comment: Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [`reaction collector`](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#reaction-collectors).

> These work quite similarly to message collectors, except that you
> apply them on a message rather than a channel. The following is an
> example taken from the documentation, with slightly better variable
> names for clarification. The filter will check for the  emoji - in
> the default skin tone specifically, so be wary of that. It will also
> check that the person who reacted shares the same id as the author of
> the original message that the collector was assigned to.

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;
};

const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });

collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
    console.log(`Collected ${reaction.emoji.name} from ${user.tag}`);
});

collector.on('end', collected => {
    console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
});
```

Read it's documentation [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionCollector).

> I would like to also know if it is possible to the randomly pair each users that have reacted to a specific role.

The [`collected`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionCollector?scrollTo=collected) property should be handy for this task.
As for adding a role/roles to a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember), use the [`add`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add) method. Read about how you can add a role to a member [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/faq.html#how-do-i-add-a-role-to-a-guild-member).